# Google Gemini API Android Error: ServerException: * GenerateContentRequest.model: unexpected model name format

Tags: android, google-gemini

I'm trying to follow the `Quickstart: Get started with the Gemini API in Android`, but I get the following server error:

```
com.google.ai.client.generativeai.type.ServerException: * GenerateContentRequest.model: unexpected model name format
```

Here is my code:

```
    @Composable
fun Greeting(name: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val generativeModel = GenerativeModel(
        // Use a model that's applicable for your use case (see "Implement basic use cases" below)
        modelName = "MODEL_NAME",
        // Access your API key as a Build Configuration variable (see "Set up your API key" above)
        apiKey = dreambig.apps.aiexpriments.BuildConfig.GOOGLE_AI_API_KEY
    )
    var story: String by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    Column(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Hello $name!",
            modifier = modifier
        )
        Button(onClick = {
            val prompt = "Write a story about a backpack."
            GlobalScope.launch {
                val response = generativeModel.generateContent(prompt)
                print(response.text)
                story = response.text.toString()
            }
        }) {
            Text("Tell me a story")
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp))
        Text(story)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify a model.

```
modelName = "MODEL_NAME"
```

You need set a valid `modelName` like this example:

```
 modelName = "gemini-pro-vision"
```

You can access details about the models from the link below.

[Gemini Models](https://ai.google.dev/models/gemini)

Comment: hehe sometimes you overthink problems and neglect the most obvious things. Recently, I've had massive server issues in other apps, and this server error just let me overthink, hehe.